# Is there a metaphorical word for "Seeing without being Seen"?

Tags: metaphors

I was wondering, there might be parts of a fort, military establishments where they employ the technique of seeing without being seen.

Please help me out by listing the words that hint at the objective - "Seeing without being seen"

For instance, the tower at the centre of the Panopticon structure, proposed by Jeremy Bentham enables this objective.

Thank you!

Comment: Questions asking for lists are usually considered  as off-topic.

Comment: What makes you think there is a list of terms? There is night vision equipment....

Comment: Before I got to the end of your question, I suspected the word you were looking for *was* "panopticon." Please edit to tell more about why that isn't an adequate metaphor. (Or, if you don't actually mean "metaphorical," perhaps "covert surveillance" is applicable.)

Comment: I thought the word was going to be “***spying***”.

Comment: From the title, I though the word was "**lurking**".

Comment: Well, forts had _loopholes_ - narrow slits through which arrows (or, later, firearms) could be shot, too small for the attackers to see in.

Comment: ....*Spying on*